# How to set nested property state with rx-angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, rx-angular

I can't seem to find a way to set the nested properties of my state.

```
// state
{
  name,
  info: {
    foo
    email
  }
}
```

My state has multiple properties, info is an object with properties as well.
I would like to add or update a property of info. I suppose I could do a `get('info')` and do `{...info ...newProp}` before setting info back to the state. But, that would cost a `get()` call.

Is there a way to update info properties with a set ? `state.set('info.foo', 'bar')`

Answer (score 0):

```
const reduceFn = (oldState: IRobotState) => {
        const rsi: any = rsiData[rsiData.length - 1];
        const live = {...oldState.live || {}, rsi: rsi.value};
        return {live};
      };
this.state.set(reduceFn);
```

Answer (score 0):

General answear will be [setAccumulator](https://www.rx-angular.io/docs/state/api/rx-state#setaccumulator)

#1 RxAngular hint: it will be better to working with flat state structure (via destruct object or setting separate property in **connect**). For example, we can watch multiple fields for update with **selectSlice**

#2 RxAngular hint: you should work with observables instead of values and try to organize just as set of services, connectcted one by one with connect and select